# Upload image with post -ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use this method to save user informations in data base. Can someone help me to upload image too in the same function ?

```
- (void)Inscription:(NSArray *)value completion:(void (^)( NSString * retour))block{


NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSArray *Param_header = @[@"username", @"password", @"email",@"first_name", @"last_name"];

// NSArray *Param_value = @[@"ali", @"aliiiiiiii", @"ali.ali@gmail.com",@"ali",@"zzzzz"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:// /Messenger/services/messenger_register"]]];
NSString *aa=[self buildParameterWithPostType:@"User" andParameterHeaders:Param_header ansParameterValues:value];
[request setHTTPBody:[aa dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                   queue: queue
                       completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error || !data) {
                               // Handle the error

                               NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                           } else {

                               NSError *error = Nil;
                               id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                               block([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"message"]]);

                           }
                       }
 ];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use third-party frameworks like AFN to upload image。
Here is sample code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *mgr = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
params[@"username"] = @"Jack";

[mgr POST:@"http:// /Messenger/services/messenger_register" parameters:params
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image.png" ofType:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];


[formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"mage/png"];
}
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"upload success!----%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"upload failed!----%@", error);
}];
```